# Form string Post redirection in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was trying to integrate Payumoney Payment gateway in one of a E Commerce site developed in MVC4. To redirect to the gateway for payment I have to submit :

```
<form id="PostForm" name="PostForm" action="https://test.payu.in/_payment" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="udf5" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="curl" value="">
    <input type="hidden" language='javascript'>
        var vPostForm = document.PostForm;
        vPostForm.submit();
    </script>
```

In ASP.Net, this is the code

```
Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strForm));
```

How to achieve this in MVC?

Thanks,
Prasant

Comment: Posted code isn't correct, is it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strForm));
```

Instead of above line of code just write :

```
Response.Write(strForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create it as partial. Put this markup in its view. And in your main view code use `@Html.RenderPartial("Payment")`